# How to create an isolated html page without any link/reference to the home page using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am new to AngualrJS. I reference index.html as my home page and I want to map a partial link which is not at all related to the home page(`index.html`); example, 
`http://www.example.com/newpage`.

Here, the newpage shouldn't have any connection with the `index.html`. and where to put my `newpage.html` in the project.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to have two differente apps. Every app needs a fixed route prior to the '#'.

So, in your case, index.html would have it's app, and newpage.html would have another one.

Comment: Thanks @felipev can you please help on how to reference with the existing app?

Comment: @Nitroushacker I'm understanding that you want to go from one app to the other. For that, you would use $window.location. $window is basically a angularjs reference to the window object (you can reed more of it here: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window))

Answer (score 0):

See there is no way to ignore the index.html, so keep the index.html as plain page without any design and create different master pages

[See the detail here how can you do it](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1207/angularjs-multiple-master-pages-with-different-design-without-show-hide) with demo.